# How to Roll back Sharepoint content editor webpart

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part, content-editor-web-part

I have content editor on my team site where I added several links. But today while adding some new links, content editor crashed. so now when I tried to open site containing content editor, browser stop working.

The quick solution is: I can delete the existing content editor and create a new one (using `?contents=1` in the corrupted team site). But since my content editor contains lot of links, so is there a way where I can roll back content editor to previous version (till yesterday afternoon)?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you have versioning enabled in the library, the contents of a Content Editor Web Part is not affected by that, as far as I know. The only way I can think of is to restore the page from your server/system backups.

Comment: That's the only way, hope you have a good backup